# What is the type of JSON Array in JSON.Net?

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net

I have following json data:

```
{
    "cgFinishing": {
        "a3colorfn": [{
                "type": "Cacah",
                "kode": "CCH"
            },
            {
                "type": "Cutting",
                "kode": "CUT"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And my JSON Class:

```
Public Class A3colorfn
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property kode As String
End Class

Public Class CgFinishing
    Public Property a3colorfn As A3colorfn()
End Class

Public Class CGSave
    Public Property cgFinishing As CgFinishing
End Class
```

I want to write a method in VB.NET that pull values from this JSON array using JSON.NET. This code works for me:

```
Public Sub fillCBfromJson(ByVal cb As ComboBox, json As Object, Optional ByVal value As String = "", Optional display As String = "")
    ....
End Sub
```

But I'd like to replace `json As Object` with something that are more specific, because I'd like to retrieve the count of items in the array (something like `Count` or `GetLength`, I cannot expose those property with `Object` type)

For your reference this code works for me...

```
Dim count As Integer = jsonObj.cgFinishing.a3colorfn.GetLength(0)
```

But I have no idea to turn it as a method.
Any help is appreciated.

More code listing:

```
Private Sub PublishDigital_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    jsonPath = Application.StartupPath + "\Addons\CG_Tools\cgSave.json"
    jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of CGSave)(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath))
    initfinishingA3()
End Sub

Public Sub initfinishingA3() 'I want to make this as a method, so I'll only need to input the Array object as argument.
    Dim cbdata As Object = jsonObj.cgFinishing.a3colorfn '<- I want to put this line as argument instead
    Dim count As Integer = jsonObj.cgFinishing.a3colorfn.GetLength(0)

    Dim myCb As New List(Of CheckBox)

    For Each cur In cbdata
        Dim cb = New CheckBox()
        tb_finishinga3.Controls.Add(cb)
        Dim txt As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cur))
        ...
        cb.Text = txt("type")
        ...
   Next
End Sub
```

Following method I wrote does not work..

```
Public Sub fillTabwithCB(ByVal cbdata As JArray, XOffset As Integer, YOffset As Integer, maxRow As Integer)
    Dim count As Integer = cbdata.Count

    Dim loopIndex As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim myCb As New List(Of CheckBox)

    For Each cur In cbdata
        Dim cb = New CheckBox()
        tb_finishinga3.Controls.Add(cb)
        Dim txt As JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cur))
        .........
        cb.Text = txt("type")
        ..........
    Next
End Sub
```

Then I tried it in this line...

```
fillTabwithCB(jsonObj.cgFinishing.a3colorfn, 7, 7, 5)
```

It generates following error:

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of
>   CG_FileManagement.A3colorfn' cannot be converted to
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.

Comment: please show how you used JSON.NET. Possibly the type is `JArray` but we can't say without seeing how you used the library.

Comment: Updated with more code.

Comment: `DeserializeObject(Of CGSave)`. You're casting the output to an instance of `GSave`. So you can write `json As GSave` elsewhere where you need it, I think.

Comment: I'll take a look into it, meanwhile I've posted more code I wrote and the error code I got.

Comment: the culprit there is `ByVal cbdata As JArray`. `a3colorfn` is not a `JArray`, it's a `A3colorfn`. You can't just arbitrarily cast objects from one type to another unrelated type. Either amend the function signature to accept the correct type, or pass an object of the correct type into it (what you choose depends on how you intended your code to work).

Comment: Makes sense, the thing is the argument wouldn't be only from that class...so I can't make it like As a3colorfn for example. Is there any way I can convert the class to specific type or it just not possible and I need to take another approach?

Comment: there are a few different ways you could achieve something that would allow you to pass different types into the method (overloading, using interfaces, passing as Object and then casting to a required type) but I can't really say what the best structure is, because it's not clear from the code what you're actually trying to achieve as the end goal.